# What is meant by calculating the delta between two config protobufs in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In Hyperledger Fabric docs, after the BYFN tutorial, there is an extension of the tutorial to add a new organization to the network. [Here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html#add-the-org3-crypto-material).

During the steps, there is a mention of *calculating the delta between two config protobuf*. There is no explanation of that in the entire documentation. I have googled for it thinking that it is a general term. I couldn't find any results there. Can anyone please explain what it is or what is the idea behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the initial configuration, aspects such as organizations and channels that are configured in the ordering service genesis block. To perform that update you need to calculate the delta (the "difference") between the original configuration and the new one so you can build a transaction based on it. `configtxlator` tool helps you to calculate it.

Comment: yes @kekomal is correct  do u need anything further feel free to create a new question